# Does Spring security JDBC authentication hit the Data base on every request

Tags: java, spring-security

I wrote one program using spring security framework and used JDBC approach using DataSource. Following is piece of code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/users/**").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
    }
}
```

This program is using default table what spring framework expect.
Now my question, because here I am using httpBasic authentication approach when I will come GET /users url, does spring framework hit the table on every request and valid user with credential or after first authentication it cache and validate against that cache.

Could someone help me to understand it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use stateless HTTP Basic, the database will *by default* be "hit" on every request. If you find that a problem you can set a **cache** like this:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).userCache(userCache);
}
```

See [UserCache javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserCache.html) for details about which cache implementations you can use.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is configured by `sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy()` when configuring `HttpSecurity`.

Unless you set it to `sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)` ,its default value is [`IF_REQUIRED`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/759e47ba846ebd47494b3304e0196875079aed26/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/SessionManagementConfigurer.java#L548) which will cache the authentication result (i.e. `SecurityContext`) in the `HttpSession`.Subsequent requests from the same session will simply get the authentication result from the session rather than hitting the database to validate the credential .

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `httpBasic()`, then the query would be performed each time - this is the nature of stateless authentication, which is what folks using `httpBasic()` are typically driving at.

You could cache the JDBC query results with an L2 cache or similar.

Or, if you are okay with some authentication state, then you could

1. add session management, as another answer indicates. Doing this means that the first request would include credentials in the Authorization header and its response would include a session cookie. Subsequent requests would send that session cookie back, instead of the Authorization header, until the session expires.
2. use a token (like an OAuth token). You can instead present your credentials to an Authorization Server. The Authorization Server will exchange this for a token that you can then supply to the Authorization header (`Authorization: Bearer`) instead of the user's credentials (`Authorization: Basic`).